# How to change the bar color in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts for building charts and the default color that I see is blue. How can I change the color to green ?

I tried adding the colors array by looking at the online API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors but may be I am not setting it at the correct place.

**Highcharts JS v4.1.9**

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Highcharts - Basic Column Chart demo!</h1>
        <div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var chart = {
                    type: 'column'
                };
                var title = {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
                };
                var subtitle = {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                };

                var xAxis = {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    crosshair: true
                };
                var yAxis = {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                };
                var tooltip = {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                };
                var plotOptions = {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                };
                var credits = {
                    enabled: false
                };

                var series = [{
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                    }];

                var json = {};
                json.chart = chart;
                json.title = title;
                json.subtitle = subtitle;
                json.tooltip = tooltip;
                json.xAxis = xAxis;
                json.yAxis = yAxis;
                json.series = series;
                json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
                json.credits = credits;
                $('#container').highcharts(json);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API says it all. Creating a green line `#009933` works by just adding it to your color array in your settings. The colors property is just an array, not an json object.

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/awemsmwm/)

```
colors:['#009933']
```

As the documentation states it will loop all your colors as long as you have something left.

> When all colors are used, new colors are pulled from the start again.

Using your syntax would look something like your series property, which is just an array too.

```
var colors = ['#009933'];
json.colors = colors;
```

Comment: Should I add this at the bottom just before the `#container` line like this ? `json.colors = colors:['#009933'];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

[One more way of doing it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/onhfLqdm/11/)

define colors array and insert in json.colors

```
var colors = ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'] ;
```