# Process json data to generate bar graph

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to create a simple highchart bar graph with JSON that returns the value something like this :

```
[{
"name":"Apple",
"price":"40",
"date":"2022-02-04"
},
{
"name":"Mango",
"price":"80",
"date":"2022-08-02"
},
{
"name":"Orange",
"price":"60",
"date":"2021-01-09"
}]
```

and here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o246u8bt/ I am trying to achieve. It is not generating the bar with the different bar colors. Is this the right way of updating the series? Here is exactly the way I want my graph to look like http://jsfiddle.net/6hkcn4qf/2/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues in your code. This is your function for ajax successful request:

```
success: function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  const processedData = [];

  for (let key in data) {
    // alert(key);
  
    processedData.push({
      name: data[key].name,
      y: data[key].price
    });
  }

  options.series.data = processedData;

  Highcharts.chart('container', options);
}
```

###### 1. Your data are strings, not numbers

Your `JSON.stringified` data are *strings*, so you're mapping strings in `y: data[key].price`.

Simply change into **=>** `y: +data[key].price`. With the *plus sign* you transform strings into numbers.

###### 2. Your `options.series` is an array, not an object

So, you are not setting anything here: `options.series.data = processedData` (as `options.series` is an array of objects, it has *indexes*, not *keys*)

Simply change this into **=>** `options.series[0].data = processedData` to create the `data` key of the first object inside the `options.series` array.

###### 3. Use Stackoverflow's internal snippets, not external ones - if possible.

As external fiddles in a couple of months may be deleted or overwritten.
Or the external site can be offline.

So, this question could become un-understandable or useless for others users in a short time.

Comment: +1. Side note: An alternative to using `+` to coerce a string to a number is to use a function such as [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat): `y: parseFloat(data[key].price)`. I have a slight preference for the function, since I always forget what the `+` does here.

Comment: @andrewJames you're right. But I'm too lazy for `parseFloat()` :))

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments. Could you also guide me on how to change the bar colors as my bar still shows the same colors

Comment: @Geek - have you researched this? For example: [How to change the bar color in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174058/how-to-change-the-bar-color-in-highcharts) - and probably several similar questions & answers. If you are truly stuck after that, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, that works well in a column chart and the similar approach does not work the same with a bar graph. Not sure, I need to dig more I believe. Thanks for the link.